# Hide Table View separator on titanium

Tags: iphone, android, titanium

Am developing one mobile application(android, iPhone)  by using Titanium 
from the Titanium development kit am using a control  **TableView** (*Titanium.UI.createTableView*),am adding **TableViewRow** on the Tableview controls. On the UI, the each row is coming with a separator (default) , but according to my requirement need to hide the separator. How is poosible ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: row will always create a separator. How long is your table? if it  is small then, you should use view instead of Table.

Comment: thanks for your replay , but i c't use view. finally i found the solution we can use var tableView = Ti.UI.createTableView({ separatorColor: 'transparent', backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF' }); it's removed/hidden the separator separatorColor:'transparent' for hiding the separator

Answer (score 0):

Create TableView with Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewSeparatorStyle.NONE:

```
Ti.UI.createTableView({separatorStyle:Ti.UI.iPhone.TableViewSeparatorStyle.NONE});
```